# Known bounds of the maximum cut of planar graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

The well-known [max cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut) asks for a largest cut of a graph $G$. A cut
of maximal size clearly corresponds to a bipartite subgraph of maximal size.
After my inquiry, in planar graphs, the maximum-cut problem is dual to the route inspection problem (the problem of finding a shortest tour that visits each edge of a graph at least once)

I would like to ask if there is some theoretical research on the **maximum cut** of the planar graph, such as finding **some upper or lower bounds**. Or for some special planar graphs such as triangulation graphs, is there a corresponding study?

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: A cut in a triangulation can't use all three edges of a face, so an upper bound is two edges from each face. This is achieved by triangulations whose dual is hamiltonian.

Comment: Thanks, Sir.  I noticed that there was some discussion about the lower bounds of the maximum cut for some graphs. [AS B B, SCOTT A D. Better Bounds for Max Cut[J]] ., but I didn't see anything talk about planar graph.

Comment: The following post on mathSE addresses the lower bound: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918960/planar-graph-contains-bipartite-subgraph. This lower bound is tight and is obtained by maximal planar graphs.